# Performance tuning on link server table joining with CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Want to tune the performance by reducing the number of `SELECT` on `OPENQUERY` by doing `JOIN` operation.

Here is how my query look like.

Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        [EmployeeFirstName], [EmployeeMiddleName],
        [EmployeeLastName], [EmployeeAddress]
    FROM 
        Employee
    WHERE 
        [EmployeeSalary] >= 200000 
)
SELECT 
    [First Name], [Fathers Husband Name], [Last Name], [Department Name]
FROM 
    OPENQUERY ([Depart], 'SELECT [First Name], [Fathers Name], [Last Name],[Department Name] 
                          FROM Department
                          INNER JOIN CTE C1 ON PATINDEX(''[First Name]'',''C1.[EmployeeFirstName]'') > 0');
```

Error:

> Invalid object name 'CTE'

Comment: Yor CTE is declared on local server, but OPENQUERY executes on linked server that has no idea of your **local** CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        [EmployeeFirstName], [EmployeeMiddleName],
        [EmployeeLastName], [EmployeeAddress]
    FROM 
        LocalServer.Database.Schema.Employee
    WHERE 
        [EmployeeSalary] >= 200000 
)
SELECT 
    [First Name], [Fathers Husband Name], [Last Name], [Department Name]
    --It's better to specify the table eg: C1.ColumnName
FROM 
    (
      SELECT [First Name], [Fathers Name], [Last Name],[Department Name] 
      FROM LinkedServer.Database.Schema.Department
      INNER JOIN CTE C1 
      ON PATINDEX([First Name],C1.[EmployeeFirstName]) > 0
    ) TBL;
```